# Is it possible to force specific ram size in linux kernel (with unrecognized sticks)?

Tags: linux, kernel, memory, gentoo, iommu

First of all I'm asking for an old PowerMac G5 Quad which ultimately is able to boot with

- 2x1GB DDR2
- 2x4GB DDR2
- 2x4GB DDR2
- 2x4GB DDR2

Problem is it utilizes only the first 2 gigs.

The other 3 pairs are identified as Unknown or something like that (in Apple Diagnostics),

Anyway I'm asking about if it's possible with Linux kernel boot arg (or some other command) to force a specific amount of physical memory to be used or not.

I tried the obvious `mem=26G` but ultimately `free -h` still only shows 1.9G.

I saw in `/dev/iommu` that the maximum address is `0x7FFFFFFF` (~2.1 G).

So is it possible to somehow hack this - to show all my ram?

*I'm running Gentoo Linux as a side note - and currently don't have access to the machine but I'm still wondering*

Comment: Does the powerpc processor in that machine have a >32 bit address space?

Comment: @MarcusMüller It's ppc64 kernel yeah. I'm 100 sure - because I also am able to use like 7 and something gigs when I fill with the old RAM banks (plus like I compiled the kernel from the ppc64 archive).